# jFreeChart: How to hide the legend?

Tags: plot, jfreechart, legend

I tried "LegendTitle", but it's not working. How I can hide the legend?
I have two graphic in one: CategoryPlot and

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(res.getString("bar_chart.title"),
                     res.getString("bar_chart.sections.title"),
                     MessageFormat.format(res.getString("bar_chart.duration.title"),  
                          res.getString("bar_chart.length.unit"), 
                          "DM_ACTIVITY", 
                          "activity_duration"),
                     dsTime);

CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
plot.setDataset(1, dsLength);
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);
plot.setRangeAxis(1, new NumberAxis(
     MessageFormat.format(res.getString("bar_chart.length.title"), 
                     dataContext.getUnitLabel(dataContext.getOverrideUnitSysId(), 
                    "CD_HOLE_SECT_GROUP", "md_hole_sect_top"))
));

StackedBarRenderer barRenderer = (StackedBarRenderer) plot.getRenderer(0);
barRenderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
LineAndShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
shapeRenderer.setSeriesShape(0, new Rectangle.Float(-10, -10, 20, 20));
shapeRenderer.setLegendShape(0, new Rectangle.Float(-5, -5, 10, 10));
shapeRenderer.setBasePaint(Color.red);
shapeRenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);
shapeRenderer.setBaseOutlinePaint(Color.white);
shapeRenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());
plot.setRenderer(1, shapeRenderer);
plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);

LegendTitle legend1 = new LegendTitle(shapeRenderer);
legend1.setVisible(false);

for (int i = 0; i < TIME_NONE; i++) {
    plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(i, Color.decode("#" + res.getString("color." + keys[i])));
}
```

Comment: `chart.removeLegend()`

Comment: Or use the factory that lets you specify `legend`.